# First couple of candles and last candle missing in historical data , derived candle time is not correct

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, stock

I am downloading historical stock option data from my broker.
From the broker, I am getting only one-minute candles.
From one-minute candle, I am creating 3-minute, 5-minute, and 15-minute candles.

**But for a few of the stocks, some days I get either the first couple of candles missing or the last candles are missing.**

I am generating 3 minutes 5 minutes and 15 minutes from 1 minute using resample method.But because of missing candles, I am getting the wrong timestamp on generated candles like getting 9:16 rather than 9:15 as the starting candle of 3 minutes.

```
                            open   high    low  close  volume        
date                                                                     
2023-11-22 15:27:00+05:30  71.65  71.35  71.65    750     750  
2023-11-22 15:28:00+05:30  71.50  70.80  71.05   1500    1500  
2023-11-22 15:29:00+05:30  71.85  71.05  71.15   3000    3000  
2023-11-23 09:16:00+05:30  74.40  74.40  74.40    250     250  
2023-11-23 09:17:00+05:30  72.00  72.00  72.00    500     500  
2023-11-23 09:18:00+05:30  71.95  71.95  71.95    250     250  
2023-11-23 09:19:00+05:30  73.00  72.00  73.00   4500    4500  
2023-11-23 09:20:00+05:30  74.05  74.05  74.05    250     250  
2023-11-23 09:21:00+05:30  75.00  73.10  75.00   2500    2500  
2023-11-23 09:22:00+05:30  75.00  73.95  74.00   1500    1500  
2023-11-23 09:23:00+05:30  74.45  74.20  74.45    750     750  
2023-11-23 09:24:00+05:30  76.00  75.00  76.00   1250    1250
```

like in the above example when I resample and generated 3 minutes candles.

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings

#regroup to get the data for different interval
#data -> in below example is dataframe
#regro -> defines the interval which i have taken as 3
def regroup_data(data,regroup_interval):
    gp = data.groupby('day')
    dfList = []
    for k, res in gp:
        resampledf = res.resample(regroup_interval, origin='start').agg(
            {'open': 'first', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'close': 'last', 'volume': 'sum'})
        resampledf.reset_index(inplace=True)
        dfList.append(resampledf)
    resSampleDF = pd.concat(dfList, ignore_index=True)
    resSampleDF.set_index('date',inplace=True)
    return resSampleDF



absoluteFileName = "C:\\Users\\learner\\stock.csv"
data_full = pd.read_csv( absoluteFileName )

data_full['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_full['date'])
data_full['day'] = data_full.apply(lambda x: x.date.date(), axis=1)
data_full.set_index('date', inplace=True)

print(data_full)

df2 = regroup_data(data_full,'3T')
print(df2)
```

**Output looks like below**

```
date                                                         
2023-11-22 15:27:00+05:30  71.65  71.35  71.05   3000    5250
2023-11-23 09:16:00+05:30  74.40  74.40  71.95    250    1000
2023-11-23 09:19:00+05:30  73.00  74.05  73.00   2500    7250
2023-11-23 09:22:00+05:30  75.00  75.00  74.00   1250    3500
```

**Now output contains time as 9:16 , 9:19 and 9:23  ideally it should be 9:15 , 9:18 , 9:21
This is happening as one starting candle data is missing**

*Is there a way to get the time as the actual time with the same data or is there is a way i can write missing candles in input data with previous candle data as keeping the previous state at missing time as well?*

Answer (score 0):

If you create pd.date_range in 3 minute increments, then the minimum in `'2023-11-23 09:15:00+05:30'` will be: 72.00, since these are lines from: `2023-11-23 09:16: 00+05:30, 2023-11-23 09:17:00+05:30`, that is, minutes 15, 16, 17. And in `2023-11-23 09:18:00+05:30` minutes 18, 19 , 20 with a minimum of 71.95.

I created a `'group_epoch'` column in df for merging (it first calculates the time in seconds since the beginning of 1970 and divides it by 60*3.

Output:

```
                        date   open   high    low  close  volume  group_epoch
0  2023-11-22 15:27:00+05:30  71.65  71.35  71.65    750     750      9448039
1  2023-11-22 15:28:00+05:30  71.50  70.80  71.05   1500    1500      9448039
2  2023-11-22 15:29:00+05:30  71.85  71.05  71.15   3000    3000      9448039
3  2023-11-23 09:16:00+05:30  74.40  74.40  74.40    250     250      9448395
4  2023-11-23 09:17:00+05:30  72.00  72.00  72.00    500     500      9448395
5  2023-11-23 09:18:00+05:30  71.95  71.95  71.95    250     250      9448396
6  2023-11-23 09:19:00+05:30  73.00  72.00  73.00   4500    4500      9448396
7  2023-11-23 09:20:00+05:30  74.05  74.05  74.05    250     250      9448396
8  2023-11-23 09:21:00+05:30  75.00  73.10  75.00   2500    2500      9448397
9  2023-11-23 09:22:00+05:30  75.00  73.95  74.00   1500    1500      9448397
10 2023-11-23 09:23:00+05:30  74.45  74.20  74.45    750     750      9448397
11 2023-11-23 09:24:00+05:30  76.00  75.00  76.00   1250    1250      9448398
```

In df1 I create pd.date_range in 3 minute increments. The 'group_epoch' column is also created and rows are removed before merging outside the trading session.

```
import pandas as pd

df = df.reset_index()
df['group_epoch'] = ((df['date'].astype(int) / 10 ** 9) / (60 * 3)).astype(int)

print(df)

start, end = '2023-11-22 00:00:00+05:30', '2023-11-23 23:59:00+05:30'
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start, end, freq='3min')})

df1['group_epoch'] = ((df1['date'].astype(int) / 10 ** 9) / (60 * 3)).astype(int)
df1 = df1[(df1['date'].dt.hour >= 9) & (df1['date'].dt.hour <= 15)]

df1 = df1.merge(df, how='left', on='group_epoch').dropna()

df1 = (df1.groupby(
    'group_epoch').agg({'date_x': 'first', 'open': 'first',
     'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'close': 'last',
     'volume': 'sum'}).reset_index().drop('group_epoch', axis=1).
       rename(columns={'date_x': 'date'}).set_index('date'))

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
                            open   high    low   close  volume
date                                                          
2023-11-22 15:27:00+05:30  71.65  71.35  71.05  3000.0  5250.0
2023-11-23 09:15:00+05:30  74.40  74.40  72.00   500.0   750.0
2023-11-23 09:18:00+05:30  71.95  74.05  71.95   250.0  5000.0
2023-11-23 09:21:00+05:30  75.00  74.20  74.00   750.0  4750.0
2023-11-23 09:24:00+05:30  76.00  75.00  76.00  1250.0  1250.0
```